# What does a game programmer and graphics programmer do?

Tags: game-design, graphics, graphics-programming

I'm quite the novice in terms of my knowledge of game development, and I'd incredibly appreciate any further insight on this. To be a bit more specific, I encountered this video, (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GyFRMr4uf4) and It documents the roles of game programmers and graphics programmers at Naughty Dog but even with the descriptions, I'm still uncertain of what those jobs actually entail. Sorry If this wasn't a suitable place for the post, but for any help thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that job titles aren't entirely standardized across the game industry, so you may find each studio or developer has their own slightly ideosyncratic twists on these terms. The best guide will be in the job description for the particular opening you're applying to, or talking to developers at that studio to find out what the role entails in their specific team & project.